# como retornar duas ou mais colunas usando o .loc ou .iloc no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

atualmente eu uso o seguinte metodo:

```
retorno = DATAFRAME.loc[:,'coluna_a'].unique()
```

onde eu retorno todos os dados unicos daquela coluna, porem so obtenho o retorno dos dados daquela coluna, eu queria obter o retorno da coluna_a e coluna_b por exemplo, usando a mesma regra de filtragem do .loc() e .unique()

*se possivel alguem souber uma forma diferente de obter esse resultado e puder compartilhar a informação comigo ficaria agradecido*

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria uma lista e passa ela como parâmetro

```
colunas_retorno = ['coluna_a','coluna_b','coluna_c']
 

retorno = DATAFRAME.loc[:,colunas_retorno].unique()
```

Comment: e como eu defino qual dessas colunas vai ser usado o filtro ?
ex: quero as colunas A B e C, porem so filtra pela coluna A